# How do I set the value of a PasswordType property?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got a `User` model defined as such:

```
class User(BaseMixin, db.Model, DictSerializable):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    email = db.Column(EmailType, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(PasswordType(
        schemes=[
            'pbkdf2_sha512',
        ],
    ))

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.username = email
        self.password = password
```

And all I want to do is set a password via the flask shell (via docker) for a user that already existed before I created the `__init__` method.

I've come to realize I can't just do the ol,

```
from project_name.models import db, User
user = User.query.first()
user.password = 'foo'
db.session.commit()
```

So please, can *anyone* help me?

Comment: Your last example is what [the documentation suggests](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#sqlalchemy_utils.types.password.PasswordType). Does that not work properly for you?

Comment: @Blender nope, my `password` remains as `None`

Comment: @Blender I'm also confused by what you mean - that documentation doesn't have anything about setting/updating the password.

Comment: The second code example in that section ("*Verifying password is as easy as ...*") shows that `target.password`'s setter automatically hashes your password and stores the hash when you do `target.password = 'b'` and then automatically hashes the other side of the equality when you do `target.password == 'b'`.

Comment: Appreciate for the clarification, but unfortunately as soon as I perform `db.session.commit()` it just wipes the `user.password` clean. Is this something I simply can not do?

Comment: It might be some incompatibility between Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy-Utils. Can you create a self-contained Flask app that illustrates the problem?

Comment: @Blender I'll give it my best shot - but it's going to take me a bit (I have basically no idea how to), I'm like a month in to learning python and as you can see I'm struggling to grasp even the simplest things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [`PasswordType`](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.password) say it relies on `sqlalchemy_utils.force_auto_coercion` being run before you define your model:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import force_auto_coercion

force_auto_coercion()

...

class User(db.Model):
    ...
```

Once you do that, the value will actually persist.